# Dagger 2 what to inject and what not

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I've been reading for a few hours but I can't find an answer. What things should I inject and what things not?

I have my `LoginViewModel` with a few injected dependencies but I'm not sure if I have to inject for example my `User` data class (among other data classes) or just instantiate it.

LoginViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val loginRepositoryImpl: LoginRepositoryImpl,
    private val baseApplication: BaseApplication,
    private val networkUtils: NetworkUtils,
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) : ViewModel() {

    fun processLogin(username: String, password: String) {
        val user = User(username, password)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

User.kt

```
data class User (
    @SerializedName("usuario")
    var user: String,
    @SerializedName("clave")
    var password: String = "",
    @SerializedName("nombre")
    var name: String = ""
)
```

Comment: `private val loginRepositoryImpl: LoginRepositoryImpl,` well that sounds like the opposite of what you should be doing.

Comment: Because of the actual implementation and not the interface? In that case yes, I need to change it, I just started to learn about DI concepts. Can you please help me with the question from the title, I'm still struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

Depends why you are using Dagger. Say you want to test the following code. loginRepositoryImpl could be accessing an authentication service over network so you'd want to provide an alternate implementation. User is just a data class, there is no value in providing a mock implementation.

```
    fun processLogin(username: String, password: String): Boolean {
        val user = User(username, password)
        val isValidLogin = loginRepositoryImpl.login(user)
        return isValidLogin
        ...
    }
```

Comment: But still if I dont want to provide an alternate implementation to `LoginRepositoryImpl` I'll still need to inject it for testing purposes like mocking its result

Comment: If using Kotlin you can also just use default constructor params and provide mocks into constructor for tests.

Comment: I've found a nice [post](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) by Misko Hevery that explains my situation

Answer (score 0):

well mate no you don't need to inject your user data and why are you injecting your base application doesn't sound right

Comment: Can you please explain why I dont need to inject it? Also why injecting application class doesnt sound right? You can have a reference to application class by extending `AndroidViewModel` if you're not using dagger for example